# Questions about DirectX11 CommandLists

Tags: c++, directx-11

I have a few questions regarding this topic, ID3D11DeviceContext::FinishCommandList, and CommandList in general which I don’t think the msdn documentation is covering very well.

1. The second argument (to the function ID3D11DeviceContext::FinishCommandList(...)), ID3D11CommandList **ppCommandList, does it have to be a new uninitialized ID3D11CommandList  object or can you reuse commandList objects?
2. Does the resulting commandList (created with the function ID3D11DeviceContext::FinishCommandList(...)), have to be released when finished with it. Or should the AddRef() and Release() be managed by the user.
3. From what I understand when using myDeferredDeviceContext->ExecuteCommandList(myCommandList, FALSE), myCommandList is merged with the commandList that is being created in myDeferredDeviceContext. If this is so can I update myCommandList using FinishCommandList(...) without affecting the merged commandList?

Regards
Karl Hansson